# C# - Data filter by datetimepicker

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I am newbie to C# and would like to give a try on it.

May I know how can I return the desire value from Database(MS Access 2007) filter by the datetimepicker?

For example:

I have a datetimepicker and a datagridview in form1, .
User to select date from datetimepicker and filtered data can show in datagridview row by row?

My main purpose would like the user to pick up a date and return data fall in that date.

Many thanks in advance!
Gary Yee

Comment: So your Access DB has some rows based on dates. Now upon user giving input, your spose to get all the rows falling in that date. right?

If so, you have to use SQL query on Access DB. Google/SO search for Access db read. Then you can pass date input as a parameter in SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have column of date/datetime in your access database, you can filter data using WHERE clause in your SQL statement for example, inside `ValueChanged` event of `DateTimePicker` control

```
DateTime dt = datetimepicker.Value;

//Connection string to connect to access database
string strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;";
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(strConn)) {
   string strSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE DateCol = '{0}'", dt);
   using (var adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, connection)) {
      DataTable table = new DataTable();
      adap.Fill(table);
      GridView1.DataSource = table;
      GridView1.DataBind();
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Waqas, 
but I got an error while debug it.

Error description: Too manny characters in character literal.
Line highlight: ('connString')

Hope you can help me...
Many thanks,

Comment: You have to replace connString with actual connection string to connect to access database of your, for help please follow this url: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access and also I have update code in my asnwer. Hope it will help

Comment: I try to compile again and this time works without error. So I can view the application, but after I select a particular date on the datetimepicker. It stop and found bugs. The error line is "adap.Fill(table);" Error description is {"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."}. Can you please help?

Comment: Please see my codes:         
private void dtp_search_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 DateTime dt = dtp_search.Value;
            string strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Project\DB_Booking.mdb;";
            string strSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE bdate = '{0}'", dt);
            OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, new OleDbConnection(strConn));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(table);
            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            //GridView1.DataBind();          
        }

Comment: replace string string strSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE bdate = '{0}'", dt) to this string strSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE bdate = #{0}#", dt)

Comment: Hi Waqas, thanks for your suggestion. It allow me to select from the datetimepicker now and return the datagridview table BUT there is no data being call. I select the date which contain information, but the datagridview only show the table header without any data. PLease see below is my DB structure: [0]ID(autonumber), [1]cname(Text), [2]bdate(Date/Time), [3]btime(Date/Time), [4]ccontact(Tex), [5]sname(Text). Hope you can help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hmm could you paste the data which you have in database? My guess is no row is being returned because of 'time', i.e. may be the date in db is 13/01/2011 10:00:00 which is not equals to 13/01/2011..

Comment: Dear Waqas. It works! I have further check on the DB field and it is datetime. I have corrected bnoth DB and application to date only. Thanks a lot for you patience! Cheers!